# Calling a method from Annotation using reflection

Tags: scala, reflection, scala-reflect

I have `Sample` class with `Size` annotation

```scala
case class Sample(
  attr: SomeTypeA
  @Size(value = 50)
  name: SomeTypeB)
```

This `Size` annotation is a class that implements `AnnotationInterface`

```scala
trait AnnotationInterface[T] {
  def getValue: T
}

class Size(value: Int) extends StaticAnnotation with AnnotationInterface[Int] {
    override def getValue: Int = value
}
```

And I have `Extractor` which is responsible for extracting class members using reflection

```scala
class Extractor[A](implicit
    tt: TypeTag[A],
    ct: ClassTag[A]
) { ...extract class members using reflection... }
```

Then I would instantiate the extractor like:

```scala
val extractor: Extractor[Sample] =
      new Extractor
```

**Question** : How can I call the method `getValue: T` inside the class `Extractor` ?

Comment: Look like X/Y for me

Comment: @cchantep Sounds like a legitimate runtime-reflection question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you annotate like

```
@Size(50) name: String
```

rather than with meta-annotations like

```
@(Size @getter @setter @field)(50) name: String
```

then `@Size` remains only on constructor parameter, not field, getter or setter. So you need to use constructor of `A`.

Try

```
class Extractor[A](implicit
                   tt: TypeTag[A],
                   ct: ClassTag[A]
                  ) {
  val annotationTree = typeOf[A]
    .decl(termNames.CONSTRUCTOR).asMethod
    .paramLists.flatten
    .flatMap(_.annotations)
    .map(_.tree)
    .filter(_.tpe =:= typeOf[Size])
    .head 

  annotationTree match {
    case q"new $_($value)" => println(value) //50
  }
}
```

if you need the `value` or

```
import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox
val tb = universe.runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader).mkToolBox()

tb.eval(tb.untypecheck(annotationTree)).asInstanceOf[Size].getValue //50
```

if you really want to call `getValue`.

By the way, if you have access to `Size` and can make it a **case** class (or case-class-like) then you can do the same mostly at compile time

```
import shapeless.Annotations

Annotations[Size, Sample].apply() // None :: Some(Size(50)) :: HNil
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Can you suggest me readings on reflection? I find this quite complicated

Comment: @yeonhoo There is tutorial https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/reflection/overview.html Runtime-reflection API is intentionally similar to compile-time reflection (macros) API so you can read also https://docs.scala-lang.org/overviews/macros/usecases.html Also there is Eugene Burmako's thesis https://infoscience.epfl.ch/record/226166/files/EPFL_TH7159.pdf